# Mysql update if else

Tags: sql, mysql

Как составить запрос?

```
UPDATE table 
если sfield равен 1 то
SET field1=CONCAT('text', field1)
если нет, то
SET field2=CONCAT('text', field2)
where id=12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишу по примеру с SO, может, поправить надо будет:

```
UPDATE table SET
    field1 = CASE
        WHEN sfield = 1 THEN CONCAT('text', field1)
        ELSE field1
    END,
    field2 = CASE
        WHEN sfield = 1 THEN field2
        ELSE CONCAT('text', field2)
    END
;
```